# jxbrowser demo crash on mac ox when view youtube video every time

Tags: youtube, chromium, jxbrowser

just as title indicated. I tried jxbtrowser demo (version 6.7.1), but it crashes every time when I look some video on youtube. It is ok when access to the main page of youtube website. It is NOT ok definitely when it is video page.

I thought it is caused by adobe flash plugin, but after uninstall it, it is still not working. It's seems that youtube use html5 player rather then flash.

> jxbrowser-helper[17661] : CGAffineTransformInvert: singular
>   matrix.

And this is the error printed on console.

Comment: I assume that this is *any* youtube video - not just a single one - am I correct?

Comment: yes, exactly! Another thing is that, jxbrowser demo would not crash when using lightweight mode, although the same message print on console. It is crash only when using heavyweight mode.